# How could I invoke a generic method with dynamically determined type parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `IndexModel` base class I use for nearly all view models that build an index table of entities:

```
public class IndexModel<TIndexItem, TEntity> : ViewModel
        where TIndexItem : MappedViewModel<TEntity>, new()
        where TEntity : new()
    {
        public IndexModel()
        {
            Items = new List<TIndexItem>();
        }

        public TIndexItem TemplateItem { get; set; }
        public List<TIndexItem> Items { get; set; }

        public virtual void MapFromEntityList(IEnumerable<TEntity> entityList)
        {
            Items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TEntity>, List<TIndexItem>>(entityList);
        }
    }
```

I feel the `TEntity` parameter is unnecessary, as `TIndexItem` is of type `MappedViewModel<TEntity>`. My problems are then twofold:

1. I would need to dynamically invoke `MapFromEntityList`, using reflection to determine what `TEntity` is. Constructing the `IEnumerable<TEntity>` parameter is fairly trivial, but  the `Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TEntity>, List<TIndexItem>>(entityList)` invocation is a challenge. How can I invoke map with dynamically built type parameters?
2. My class has the constraint `where : MappedViewModel<TEntity>, new()`. This is not too big a problem, as I can make this less specific, e.g. `where TIndexItem : ViewModel, new()`, where `ViewModel` is an 'untyped' base class for all my view models. Then I can only do the `TEntity` specific stuff like the mapping call if `TIndexItem` is a `MappedViewModel<TEntity>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
public class IndexModel<TEntity> : ViewModel
    where TEntity : new()
{
    public IndexModel()
    {
        Items = new List<MappedViewModel<TEntity>>();
    }

    public MappedViewModel<TEntity>TemplateItem { get; set; }
    public List<MappedViewModel<TEntity>> Items { get; set; }

    public virtual void MapFromEntityList(IEnumerable<TEntity> entityList)
    {
        Items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TEntity>, List<MappedViewModel<TEntity>>>(entityList);
    }

}
```

Comment: So simple, yet so elusive. Wood for the trees etc. Thank you.

Comment: np, sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes:) especially when you have looked at the same thing one and over again

Comment: Unfortunately I had not practically tried this before, but it has a number of defects I will elucidate on later, so I must retract my acceptance. You still get a point for being very close though.